# Autopilot and Studio integration

Tags: twilio, ivr

The memory is giving null("") after the task is completed.
can i access the autopilot collected answer again back in studio ?
i just have a task which asks the app date  and the im trying to sent the interpreted value to HTTP in studio
{

```
    "collected_data": {

            "status": "complete",

            "answers": {

                    "answer": "2020-01-22",

                    "filled": true,
                    "attempts": 1,
                    "validate_attempts": 1,
                    "confirm_attempts": 0,
                    "confirmed": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

but the memory shows empty

Answer (score 0):

is this for Voice?
Check in the Autopilot payload if the variable is directly under the widget i.e. instead of widget.memory.VARIABLE_NAME, if you can find it as widget.VARIABLE_NAME